# post multiple buttons or links with different arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to post with three buttons and with different arguments, for Search button two parameters are passed (fromDate and ToDate) but for other two buttons Export to pdf and excel three parameters are passed (fromDate, toDate, format). How i can pass third 'format' parameter to export buttons.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Summary", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", style = "margin:20px 0 25px 0" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.TextBox("FromDate", "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "From Date" }) 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.TextBox("ToDate", "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "To Date" }) 
        </div>
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>

        <button type="submit" id="exportPdf" >Export to PDF</button>
        <button type="submit" id="exportExcal" >Export to EXCEL</button>
    }
```

Controller method:

```
 public ActionResult Summary(String FromDate, string ToDate, string format)
    {
 //my code         
}
```

P.S: i don't want to use jquery ajax here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a button name to identify the type of the file:

Html:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn-default" name="format" value="TypeX">Search</button>
<button type="submit" id="exportPdf"  name="format" value="PDF">Export to PDF</button>
<button type="submit" id="exportExcal" name="format" value="EXCEL">Export to EXCEL</button>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Summary(String FromDate, string ToDate, string format)
{
    if (format == "PDF")
       // do something
    else if (format == "EXCEL")
       // do something
    else
       // do something
}
```